# ggplot error - "cannot coerce class ‘c("ScaleContinuousPosition", "ScaleContinuous", "Scale", "ggproto", ’ to a data.frame"

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Suppose I'm trying a super simple `ggplot` plot on the `iris` data and it looks like this:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(5, 8)) %>%
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 6, y = 5, label = "We Love Flowers!", color = "#619CFF", size = 8)
```

For some reason, it throws this error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘c("ScaleContinuousPosition", "ScaleContinuous", "Scale", "ggproto", ’ to a data.frame
```

What gives? What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Listen, we've all been there. Switching between `dplyr` and `ggplot` and forgetting to switch between the `%>%` pipe and the `+` operator. Happens to the best of us!

The corrected code is the following:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(5, 8)) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 6, y = 5, label = "We Love Flowers!", color = "#619CFF", size = 8)
```

Comment: This makes me feel better about myself. :)